# Qt additonal library for plot dial ,bars and other objects?

Tags: qt, qwt, qcustomplot

I want to put some good looking objects on my application like plots, dials and other objects. QCustomPlot is available and I think that will be okay for plots but objects available in QWT are very old looking, I want some objects which adds some stars to my application. If any then please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of "good looking" there is no difference between Qwt or QCustomPlot. When using the same brushes and pens they look the same.

For the dials, sliders, knobs etc. most more modern looking versions are usually done with Qt/Quick nowadays. But IMHO this technology has failed for the desktop ( Qt/Quick Controls 1 has officially been given up ) and I'm not aware of many activities in the widgets area.

So I'm afraid your best choice is to use Qwt and to overload the methods used for rendering so that they look like expected.

You might also want to try style sheets. At least Qwt supports them to some degree.